# Java efficiency Hashmap get method

Tags: java, hashmap

So my question is probably a bit basic and a bit of an overkill. But what I want to ask is whether it is more efficent to use the same Hashmap get method multiple times. Or to point an object on one of the get methods and then work with this temporary object. I wrote a little bit of code to visualize it.

```
    HashMap<String, MyClass> stringCounter = new HashMap<>();
    stringCounter.put(..., ...); // ...

    if(stringCounter.containsKey(name)) stringCounter.get(name).remove();
    else stringCounter.get(name).add();

    MyClass myClass = stringCounter.get(name);
    if(stringCounter.get(otherName).remove) myClass.remove();
    else myClass.add();
```

Comment: `stringCounter.get(name).add();` will throw a `NullPointerException`, so you might want to worry about that first.

Comment: Yea I know, but it is about the principle, the whole code wouldn't work that great :D

Comment: `containsKey/get` does two hash lookups, this can be converted to `get` with a `null check`

Comment: I would save into a temp variable if you want to do multiple ops on it. If not then just do an one op off of get()

Comment: Almost certainly, in every common situation, it will be faster to store the reference and reuse it than to `get` the same key over and over. It, in fact, is faster to `get` and check for `null` than to call `containsKey` followed by `get`. But, as with all these things, don't take an internet random's word for it - test test test!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer : get your instance once, then work with it, this will be faster and cleaner to read also.
When you get in the hashmap, internaly it does a lookup, the jvm may or may not detect that it could be optimized. But as you are not sure just

```
Object instance = map.get(key);
if(instance != null {
    instance.doThis();
    instance.doThat();
}
```

Comment: Quick and simple answer. Thank you :D

Comment: thanks ... in addition  testing map.get(key) not null is equivalent to test on map.contains(key), so you save a call by doing directly a get(key) you will have your instance or null which mean that it found nothing

Comment: "_the jvm may or may not detect that it could be optimized_" - it will not under any circumstances optimise this.`Optional` is with a mention too.